# How to set the scrollbar to move at last line in multiline textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net. How to set the scrollbar to move at last line in multiline textbox at client side?

Comment: I suspect you can't. I guess this is a brower implementation choice, maybe depending on system settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `ClientIDMode="Static"` so you can reference the textarea from jQuery using its ID:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

And add this script after jQuery script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTextBox').scrollTop($('#myTextBox')[0].scrollHeight - $('#myTextBox').height());
});
```

I was curious about compatibility so I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE9 and it works. :)

Here is a jsFiddle example of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/g9KBB/

Answer (score 1):

possible solution with jquery (worked for me in chrome 19):

```
$('#wmd-input').scrollTop($('#wmd-input').height())
```

where `wmd-input` is the id of the textarea

Comment: @Kanavi: actually this only scrolls down the height of one screen, it might appear it works if there is not much text contained in the textarea but if there are more than 2 pages it won't work. Check my answer for a solution.

Comment: @Kanavi: Trust me, this only scrolls one page down. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/QCsz6/

Answer (score 0):

```
function f(ta_id) {
        var d = document, ta, rng;
        if (d.all) {
            ta = d.all[ta_id];
            if (ta && ta.createTextRange) {
                rng = ta.createTextRange();
                rng.collapse(false);
                rng.select();
            }
        }
    }
    function SetTextBox(ID) {
        var TextBoxes = document.getElementById(ID.id);
        if (TextBoxes != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < TextBoxes.length; i++) {
                f(TextBoxes[i].id);
            }
        }
    }
```